# Finding semi-axes of an ellipsoid.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

This might seem like a really elementary question, but I can't find any answer to it, so there I ask.

Let $B[0;1] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \left\|x\right\| \leq 1\}$, where $\left\| \cdot \right\|$ is the euclidean norm. Now I define an ellipse E as:
$$
E=\{Ax : x \in B[0;1]\} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \left\|A^{-1}y\right\| \leq 1\},
$$
where $A$ stands for linear transformation from ball to an elipse.

First question is if the above definition is correct? Does it suffice for $A$ to satysfy only the requirement $\det(A) \neq 0$ or has it to be positive-definite?

I also can't find any reasonable way to calculate semi-axes of E. Any help or **sending away to other** **sources** (where i can read about this matter in or not in depth) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ellipsoid really needs to have orthogonal axes. That means the matrix needs to be symmetric and invertible. If the eigenvalues are positive, then the eigenvalues are the lengths of the principle axes. If you have positive eigenvalues $\lambda_j$, then the ellipsoid is a rotation of the familiar ellipsoid equation
$$
     \lambda_1 x_1^{2}+\lambda_2 x_2^{2}+\cdots+\lambda_n x_n^{2} \le 1.
$$